# Unable to locate package lesstif2 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: package-management

```
E: Unable to locate package lesstif2
```

got this error in Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Could you add more info about what you were trying to do, like which command you run?

Answer (score 1):

The latest Ubuntu release with `lesstif2` was Precise Pangolin (12.04). You could install the package:

```
wget -P ~ http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/l/lesstif2/lesstif2_0.95.2-1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i ~/lesstif2_0.95.2-1_amd64.deb
```

---

Find `lesstif`-packages for your system

```
apt-cache search lesstif | awk '$1~/lesstif/ {print}'
```

Answer (score 0):

sometimes this happens when the package is actually prefaced with something like lib:

```
$ apt-cache search less | grep 'lesstif'
libpacklib-lesstif1-dev - CERNLIB data analysis suite - core GUI library (development files)
libpacklib-lesstif1-gfortran - CERNLIB data analysis suite - core GUI library
libpawlib-lesstif3-dev - CERNLIB PAW library (Lesstif-dependent part - development files)
libpawlib-lesstif3-gfortran - CERNLIB PAW library (Lesstif-dependent part)
pcb-lesstif - printed circuit board (pcb) design program - LessTif interface
vim-lesstif - Vi IMproved - enhanced vi editor (transitional package)
```